# Python: sorting a list according to the resulting order on its copy

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

[Related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696836/4398166): in the final part I'm looking for a quicker method than a nested for loop.

Say we have a list `a = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_n]`. We create a *deep* copy of `a` called `b = [b_0, b_1, ..., b_n]`, in which `b_i` and `a_i` are identical objects but stored separately. Now we perform a certain sorting algorithm `some_sort` on `b` to get an ordering `order_b = [b'_0, b'_1, ..., b'_n]` in which those `b'_i` are the <strike>same objects</strike> objects in `b` permuted (since the `some_sort` algorithm is destructive, elements in `order_b` are no longer identical to those in `b`, but the references are maintained). Now, I want `a` to be sorted according to the same ordering in `order_b`, i.e., get an ordering `order_a = [a'_0, a'_1, ..., a'_n]` which is a permutation from `a` in the same way as `order_b` is permuted from `b` , but I can't perform the sorting algorithm `some_sort` on `a` because that algorithm is destructive. Is there any quick way to do this?

Example: `a = [a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3]`, deep copy of `a` is `b = [b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3]`. The resulting ordering on `b` is `order_b = [b_3, b_2, b_0, b_1]`, then what I want is to obtain `order_a = [a_3, a_2, a_0, a_1]` according to `order_b`.

Comment: Given `order_b` is just a copy, can't you just `deepcopy` and assign to `order_a`. Without more details, its hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AChampion I'm sorry they are not exactly identical to `b`. See my edit.

Comment: @AChampion to be precise, `a` is a list of `node` instances (I have created a `Node` class with attributes `name` and `parents` (parent nodes)) forming a graph. When `some_sort` acts on `b`, it will alter the `parents` attribute for some of its memebers. So members in `order_b` are actually those in `b` first altered, then sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import copy   
a = [2,4,3,1]
Out[94]: [2, 4, 3, 1]
#create a deep copy of a
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
Out[96]: [2, 4, 3, 1]
#add index of b and its value to a tuple
b1 = [(v,k) for k, v in enumerate(b)]
Out[98]: [(2, 0), (4, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
#sort b1 (can using whatever criteria for sorting)
b1 = sorted(b1)
Out[100]: [(1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
#extract elements from a using the order of b1.
[a[e] for e in [e[-1] for e in b1]]
Out[101]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you keep the original `b_i` reference in `b'_i`, so you can create a reverse lookup of `{b_i: idx}`, e.g. (pseudo):

```
mapping = {b'_i->b_i: idx for idx, b'_i in enumerate(order_b)}
[m for m, n in sorted(zip(a,b), key=lambda x: mapping[x[1]])]
```

Demo, take a list of numbers and letters, randomize the letters and return the numbers in the same order as the randomize letters:

```
In [1]:
import random
a = list(range(10))
b = list('abcdefghij')
b_ = random.sample(b, k=len(b))
''.join(b_)

Out[1]:
'idfehbgacj'

In [2]:
mapping = {k: idx for idx, k in enumerate(b_)}
[m for m, n in sorted(zip(a,b), key=lambda x: mapping[x[1]])]

Out[2]:
[8, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 6, 0, 2, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `idx`?

Comment: `idx` is the index given by `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 0):

i have simple solution for this:

a_ = [ a[i] for i in (b.index(j) for j in b_) ]

```
        _or_
```

b_perm = [ b.index(j) for j in b_ ]
a_     = [ a[i] for i in b_perm ]

```
import random
a = list(range(10))
b = list('abcdefghij')
b_ = random.sample(b, k=len(b))

b_ = ['c', 'b', 'f', 'i', 'e', 'a', 'h', 'g', 'j', 'd']

a_ = [a[i] for i in (b.index(j) for j in b_)]

a_ = [2, 1, 5, 8, 4, 0, 7, 6, 9, 3]
```